# How to use STOMP for connecting with ActiveMQ in React js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, activemq-classic, stomp

Can anyone provide successful implementation of Stomp using the latest version of ActiveMQ 5.x using the React N? How to connect and publish to the queue?

I have below questions:

1. I have to retrieve the data from consumer and do some add some boolean value and send it to publish.
2. How can I keep the connection alive because continuously I will get message in queues.
3. How can I implement this in React.js in simple manner (any plugins)

I tried with JavaScript, and it works as expected.

**consumer.js**

```js
const Stomp = require("stomp-client");
const stompClient = new Stomp("127.0.0.1",61613);

stompClient.connect( function(sessionId){
    console.log("consumer connected");
    stompClient.subscribe("/queue/<name>",function(body){
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

**producer.js**

```js
const Stomp = require("stomp-client");
const stompClient = new Stomp("127.0.0.1",61613);

stompClient.connect( function(sessionId){
   console.log("producer connected"); 

   stompClient.publish("/queue/<name>",function(body){
      console.log(body);
      console.log(typeof(body));
      //JSON.stringify(body);
  });
   stompClient.disconnect();
});
```

This is what I tried in React.JS (which failed):  here i can able to connect and after that if i call subscribe with que name it is not giving any response

```js
import './App.css';

import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import { Client, Message } from '@stomp/stompjs';

function App() {

  const clientdata =  new Client(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    clientdata.configure({
      brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:61614/stomp',
      onConnect: (frame) => {
        console.log('onConnect');
        console.log(frame);
         clientdata.subscribe('/queue/<quename>',info => {
          console.log(info);
         })      

        console.log(subscription);

      },
      // Helps during debugging, remove in production
      debug: (str) => {
       // console.log(new Date(), str);
      }
    });

    client.activate();

    
  }, []);

  return (
    <div >
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When i tried the above code I am getting only connected log and I'm not able to subscribe any thing and not seeing anything.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages from the client-side or broker-side? Please share those, and your activemq.xml

Comment: @JustinBertram yes in javascript it is working fine and im unable to implement the same in react and using Active mQ5 latest version

Comment: @JustinBertram Do u know any procedure for implementing activemq in react ?

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are the local device. React Native runs on devices that probably aren't also running the message broker. You should use the external network address for your message broker

Comment: @Phil im using React.js

Comment: @JustinBertram  i am running on localhost and  ws://localhost:61614/stomp' it is connecting and if i remove stomp nothing getting connecting and  if i get a proper plugin for connecting react with activemq via stomp it will be great

Comment: @JustinBertram i need to add debug in the code

Comment: @Madpop sorry, I though that's what you meant by _"React N"_

Comment: @Phil No im trying react.js but unable to find any package for react do u know any package ?

Comment: @JustinBertram i checked this article and tried with 61613 also not connected https://stomp-js.github.io/stomp-websocket/codo/extra/docs-src/Upgrade.md.html and if it is not how can we connect  ?

Comment: @JustinBertram it is listening to 61614 and i checked this in activeMq connections tabs in  local portal

Comment: @JustinBertram In javascript i used https://www.npmjs.com/package/stomp-client package but it is not working in react

Comment: Did you try this article: https://medium.com/@mackplevine/using-activemq-with-node-js-stomp-and-http-b251ce8d995